# SAS find non-zero minimum in row

Tags: sas, min

Does anybody know how to find the non-zero minimum in a row using the min function in SAS? Or any other option in SAS code?

Current code:

```
PIP_factor = `min(PIPAllAutos, PIPNotCovByWC, PIPCovByWC, PIPNotPrincOpByEmpls);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use an array solution, ie

```
array pipArray pip:; *or whatever;
PIP_factor=9999;
do _n = 1 to dim(pipArray);
  if pipArray[_n] > 0 then 
   PIP_factor = min(PIP_factor,pipArray[_n]);
end;
```

Or somesuch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, using the IFN function:

```
data null_;

   PIPAllAutos = 2;
   PIPNotCovByWC = .;
   PIPCovByWC = 0;
   PIPNotPrincOpByEmpls = 1;

   PIP_factor = min(ifn(PIPAllAutos=0,          . ,PIPAllAutos)
                  , ifn(PIPNotCovByWC=0,        . ,PIPNotCovByWC)
                  , ifn(PIPCovByWC=0,           . ,PIPCovByWC)
                  , ifn(PIPNotPrincOpByEmpls=0, . ,PIPNotPrincOpByEmpls)
                );
   put PIP_factor=;
run;
```

Note the `min` function ignores missing values; the `ifn` function sets zero values to missing.

Might be more typing than it's worth; offered only as an alternative.  There are many ways to skin the cat.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* For each row, find the variable name corresponding to the minimum value */
proc iml;
use DATASET; /* DATASET is your dataset name of interest */
read all var _NUM_ into X[colname=VarNames]; /* read in only numerical columns */
close DATASET;

idxMin = X[, >:<];         /* find columns for min of each row */
varMin = varNames[idxMin]; /* corresponding var names */
print idxMin varMin;
```

For Max:

```
idxMax = X[, <:>];
```

I wasn't familiar with the operator above, SAS provides a helpful table for IML operators:

[image: IML Operators]

In `PROC IML` you can also create new datasets/append the results to your old one if you need them later on.

Full blog post: [source](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/05/21/find-the-minumum-value-in-each-row.html), **all credit goes to Rick Wicklin at SAS**

edit: For the non-zero part, I would just do a `PROC SQL` using a `WHERE variable is not 0` to filter before feeding it in the `PROC IML`. I am sure it can be done within `PROC IML`, but I just started using it myself. So, please comment if you know a way around it in `PROC IML` and I will include the fix.

Comment: saslist.com is a web site that steals blog posts written by others and does not give them credit. ALL CREDIT goes to the original post at http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/05/21/find-the-minumum-value-in-each-row/

Comment: @Rick Sorry about that - didn't know any better then. Pointed to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This one doesn't suffer from 9999 limitation of the approved answer.

```
%macro minnonzero/parmbuff;
  %local _argn _args _arg;
  /* get rid of external parenthesis */
  %let _args=%substr(%bquote(&syspbuff),2,%length(%bquote(&syspbuff))-2);
  %let _argn=1;
  min(
  %do %while (%length(%scan(%bquote(&_args),&_argn,%str(|))) ne 0);
    %let _arg=%scan(%bquote(&_args),&_argn,%str(|));
    %if &_argn>1 %then %do;
      ,
    %end;
    ifn(&_arg=0,.,&_arg)
    %let _argn=%eval(&_argn+1);
  %end;
  );
%mend;
```

You call it with pipe-separated list of arguments, e.g.

```
data piesek;
  a=3;
  b="kotek";
  c=%minnonzero(a|findc(b,"z");
  put c; /* 3, "kotek" has no "z" in it, so findc returns 0 */
run;
```